# mysql2でrails db:createすると、Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;と出てしまって解決できません！助けてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, database

rails でアプリ開発をしていて、sqlite3から、mysqlにアプリ作成後に変更しました。gemを入れて、database.ymlも変更し、でデータベースを作成しようとしたところ、エラーが発生してしまいました。調べたものの原因はわからずにいます。主に何が原因なのでしょうか？是非、回答お願いします!
下記に、database.ymlと、コンソールのエラー文を載せておきました。database.ymlのpasswordの部分はまだ、環境変数を行っていないので、伏せてあります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
最後に、database.ymlのdatabase:の記述で先ほどエラーが出ていたので、ファイルを変えたら解決しましたが、自信がないので是非、確認よろしくお願いします！
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　回答者が自分の手元で試す際にコピー＆ペーストができず回答しにくくなってしまうため、ソースコードやエラーメッセージはスクリーンショットではなく文字列のコピー＆ペーストになっているよう [edit] いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: ついでに Rails のバージョン情報もあると嬉しいです。回答者が問題を再現する助けになるからと、後からこのご質問を見に来た方の参考になるかもしれないからです。